# Update D3js bilevel partition with new JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to update [this graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371) (custom version). This graph is linked to a form and when the user submit it the datas are saved in the db and the json file is updating.

How can I update the graph with the updated JSON file ?

Comment: You need to run the code inside the JSON callback again and add handling of the update and exit selections.

Comment: Ok, can you show me an example that help me to understand ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples for this in particular, but the general pattern is well-described e.g. in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Comment: ok, I will try to understand this